# NaN when I run this script

Tags: javascript, html

Why do I get `NaN` for MOYENNE when I click the "enregistrer resultat" button. Everything else comes up okay but I get `NaN` for MOYENNE.

Sorry that it is in French but my school is French so I used French variable names and function and object names. This program is a simple HTML display with a some JavaScript very basic.

Function `Etudiant` is an object fyi. Don't pay attention to any of the functions except the function `Etudiant`, function `enregistrer()`, function `afficherMembre()` this is the function that takes the info and combines them into a the wanted result and stores them into the `lesInfos` variable. Function `afficherMoyenne()` is where I calculate the average of the 5 grades.

Here's the code:

```
var nbEtudiants = 0;        // nombre d'étudiants
var MAX_ETUDIANTS = 5;  // nombre maximum d'étudiants
var NOTE_MIN = 0, NOTE_MAX = 100;
var etudiant1, etudiant2, etudiant3, etudiant4, etudiant5;

function Etudiant (nomFourni, prenomFourni, note1, note2, note3, note4, note5){
    this.noEtudiant = 2014000 + nbEtudiants;
        this.nom = nomFourni.toUpperCase();
        this.prenom = prenomFourni.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                    prenomFourni.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        this.note1 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value;
        this.note2 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote2.value;
        this.note3 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote3.value;
        this.note4 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote4.value;
        this.note5 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote5.value;
        this.listerInfos = afficherMembre;
        this.moyenne = afficherMoyenne();
    }
}

function enregistrer (){
    if (nbEtudiants == MAX_ETUDIANTS){
        window.alert("DÉSOLÉ... le club n'accepte plus de nouveaux membres...");
        return;
    }
    nbEtudiants ++;
    switch(nbEtudiants){
        case  1 : etudiant1 = new Etudiant(document.monFormulaire.txtNom.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtPrenom.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote2.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote3.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote4.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote5.value);
                  window.alert(etudiant1.listerInfos());
                  break;
        case  2 : etudiant2 = new Etudiant(document.monFormulaire.txtNom.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtPrenom.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote2.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote3.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote4.value,
                      document.monFormulaire.txtNote5.value);                                   
                  window.alert(etudiant2.listerInfos());
                  break;
    }

    function afficherMembre () {
        var lesInfos = this.noEtudiant + " " + this.prenom + " " +  this.nom + " " +" MOYENNE: "   + " " + this.moyenne;
        return lesInfos;
    }

    function afficherMoyenne () {
        var moyenne;
        moyenne = parseInt(((parseInt(this.note1) + (parseInt(this.note2)) + (parseInt(this.note3)) + (parseInt(this.note4)) + (parseInt(this.note5))) / 5))
        return moyenne;
    }
```

Comment: You certainly need to break down this wall of code. No one wants to crwal all through it. Try to reduce it to the important parts.

Comment: this is a giant wall of text.  I am too intimidated to even read it...consider checking out the [guidelines for how to ask a question at stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "bit of code"?! Holly smokes that's 263 lines long!!! 8o

Comment: It's difficult for me to follow the flow of this program when the variables and comments are in French.

Comment: NaN stands for "Not a Number". Check if you are have an expression where a variable is not a number as expected.

Comment: I did check i don't get it everything is numbers i even use parseInt to double make them into numbers lol

Comment: Please try find a reasonable title for your question.

Comment: Do a cast for the variables that you are using in your calculation: number(variable1) * number(variable2). If one or more of those variables are showing up with a non-numeric value like a character or empty, you will have the NaN result. This is basic stuff. I recommend you to study js a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `afficherMoyenne`, you are not bound to your object `Etudiant`. The this becomes a reference to the `window` class.

#### You can make the method as a member of your class

```
Etudiant.prototype.afficherMoyenne = function () {... the code for your moyenne }
```

#### Call the method bounded to your class

```
afficherMoyenne.call(this);
```

#### Pass the values to the method

```
function Etudiant (nomFourni, prenomFourni, note1, note2, note3, note4, note5) {
    ...
    this.note1 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value;
    this.note2 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote2.value;
    this.note3 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote3.value;
    this.note4 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote4.value;
    this.note5 = document.monFormulaire.txtNote5.value;
    afficherMoyenne(this.note1, ...)
```

### Pro tip

You can also try to see the value of `document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value` and looking in the console.

```
console.log(document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value)
```

It could help you find out why the values are NaN

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH HOURS SPENT TRYING TO FIGURE THIS OUT LOVE YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you are assigning `this.moyenne`.

In your class `Etudiant`, you have this line here:

```
this.moyenne = afficherMoyenne();
```

When you call `afficherMoyenne()`, the `context` of `this` within `afficherMoyenne` is not the instance of `Etudian` - rather, it's `window`.

So this logic:

```
    var moyenne;

    moyenne = parseInt(((parseInt(this.note1) + (parseInt(this.note2)) + (parseInt(this.note3)) + (parseInt(this.note4)) + (parseInt(this.note5))) / 5))

    return moyenne;
```

And specifically things like `this.note1` are not referencing the instance property (`document.monFormulaire.txtNote1.value;`) but rather, it's looking for `window.note1` and so on.

To address this issue, you can bind `this` using `.bind` or call the function using `call` or `apply` and passing in the correct context. Something like this:

```
this.moyenne = afficherMoyenne.call(this);
```

Here are three JS Fiddles:

- [The first is your existing code (which doesn't work)](http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/x19frtom/)
- [The second is an update using `.call` and passing `this` as the `context`.](http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/x19frtom/1/)
- [Finally, the third is calling `bind` and passing `this` (which returns the bound function) and then immediately invoking that function.](http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/x19frtom/2/)

Here's more information about `this` and `context` via MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU ARE A GOD AND AMAZING EXPLANATION!